# запрос с группировкой и джоином

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица комментариев, в которой нас интересуют поля `uid`, `user_id`. Так вот, нужно выбрать из этой таблицы все уникальные `user_id`, количество записей, в которых он встречается и `Uid` этих записей.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(uid SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `comments` 
WHERE user_id> 0 
GROUP BY user_id
```

это делается так.

Есть и вторая таблица `rates`, в которой нас интересует поле `rate_value`. В этой таблице есть ключ `comment_id`, который соответствует `uid` из первой таблицы. Записи из первой таблицы может соответствовать несколько записей из второй.

Можно ли как-то выбрать соответствующие записи из второй таблицы джоинами в одном запросе или только в двух?

Comment: покажите код как вы сделали с двумя запросами? так как можно сделать с вложенними запросами. тут не понятно что делать с значениями rate_value. суммировать или собирать с запятыми ...

Comment: желательно конечно чтобы получился вложенный массив rate_value, но если так нельзя, то можно и через запятую. Двумя запросами было бы так, из получившейся в первом случае строки c uid, был бы такой запрос select * from rates where comment_id in('полученная строка  с uid')

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что в первом случае получится большое количество записей, и не хотелось бы потом в цикле запускать второй запрос, так как их будет много

Comment: @Vadim.K, может быть, в итоговой таблице вам нужна сумма `rate_value`?

Comment: нет, нужно количество 1 и -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cou, user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(uid SEPARATOR ', '), GROUP_CONCAT(rate_values SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `comments` c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT comment_id, GROUP_CONCAT(rate_value SEPARATOR ', ') rate_values
  FROM rates
  GROUP BY comment_id
) r ON comment_id = uid
WHERE user_id> 0 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: огромное спасибо. вы мне сегодня очень помогли